# SFML threading error

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, sfml

A friend and I are making a simple multiplayer game to practice our coding. Unfortunately we have encountered a problem. The SFML threading system (Not using std::thread because my compiler doesn't support it yet) is giving me an error.

> ||=== Build: Debug in Clear Void (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   C:\Users\Name\Documents\Coding\SFML work\Clear_Void\src\GameScreen.cpp||In constructor 'GameScreen::GameScreen()':|
>
> C:\Users\Name\Documents\Coding\SFML work\Clear_Void\src\GameScreen.cpp|9|error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&GameScreen::startThread' [-fpermissive]|
>
> C:\SFML-TDM471x32\include\SFML\System\Thread.inl||In instantiation of 'void sf::priv::ThreadFunctor::run() [with T = void (GameScreen::*)()]':|
>
> C:\Users\Name\Documents\Coding\SFML work\Clear_Void\src\GameScreen.cpp|53|required from here|
>
> C:\SFML-TDM471x32\include\SFML\System\Thread.inl|39|error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((sf::priv::ThreadFunctor*)this)->sf::priv::ThreadFunctor::m_functor (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((sf::priv::ThreadFunctor*)this)->sf::priv::ThreadFunctor::m_functor) (...)'|
>
> ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s)) ===|

Here is my code: 
GameScreen.h

```
class GameScreen : public Screen
{
public:
    GameScreen();

    void handleInput(sf::RenderWindow&) override;
    void update(sf::RenderWindow&, sf::View&) override;
    void render(sf::RenderWindow&) override;

    void startThread();


private:
    sf::Vector2f moveVal;
    Network network;
    Events eventManager;

    Map m_map;

    sf::Thread networkThread;
};
```

GameScreen.cpp (Relevant Section)

```
GameScreen::GameScreen()
: networkThread(&startThread)
{
    network.Connect();
}
```

I checked the SFML threading tutorials and according to them, that should work. Please help.

Comment: `startThread` should be static.  And use a newer version of gcc.

Comment: well, you might as well make that an answer as it fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

startThread should be static.  In general, thread functions can't call non-static member functions.